# Multiple inheritance in Python: how does super().__init__ affect?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can you please explain the following contradiction?

For this code:

```
class CL1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CL1, self).__init__()
        print "class 1"


class CL2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #super(CL2, self).__init__()
        print "class 2"


class CL3(CL2, CL1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CL3, self).__init__()
        print "class 3"


instance = CL3()
```

the output is:

> class 2
>
> class 3

However, if I uncomment the line:

```
#super(CL2, self).__init__()
```

I get the output:

> class 1
>
> class 2
>
> class 3

I don't understand why applying to the superclass of CL2 invokes the constructor of CL1. CL1 is not the constructor of CL2.

The link: [How does multiple inheritance work with the super() and different __init__() arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855087/how-does-multiple-inheritance-work-with-the-super-and-different-init-arg) 
doesn't explain why the line:

```
#super(CL2, self).__init__()
```

invokes the constructor of a class that is not the superclass of the class calling it.

Comment: I use version 2.7

Comment: To be specific, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30187306/2063361

Comment: "depth-first left-to-right traversal" + "removing duplicates expect for the last" - thanks

Comment: Nice find, @anonymous! Does that answer your question CrazySynthax? If so, we can close this question as a duplicate of that one. It helps to bear in mind that the `super.__init__` calls all get passed the _instance_ that's currently being initialized, so when you do  (eg) `super(CL3, self).__init__()` the `CL2.__init__` gets called with the new `CL3` instance as `self`, so the `CL3` MRO determines what happens next.

Comment: we can close it

Comment: Well, it's already closed as a duplicate, but I think the question anonymous found is better than the one chosen by  Jean-François Fabre, which you've already said didn't help you. :) If you like, we can change the "dupe target" to anonymous's one.