# super function in Multiple inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have written this code in python 3.4 and used classes. I have implemented multiple inheritance in this code with super() function. And i want to call the **init**() function of library class. But i am unable, can anyone tell me the mistake?

**code**

```
class college:
    def __init__(self, rollno):
        print("Roll no:", rollno)

class library:
    def __init__(self, libcardno):
        print("Library card no:", libcardno)

class student(college, library):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("Name:", name)
        super().__init__(5560)
        super().__init__(60)
```

**output**

```
>>> obj = student("John")
Name: John
Roll no: 5560
Roll no: 60
```

Just understand the question, it's not a duplicate of another one.

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods?rq=1

Comment: i want to use super() in multiple inheritance not in single inheritance. @Jerrybibo

Comment: If you look at the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/576183/5606836) of that question, there is a link to more information on `super()` in a MI environment.

Comment: Quite lengthy and messy. @Jerrybibo

Comment: I would question whether multiple inheritance is the right choice here. A student _is a_ college or _is a_ library?

Comment: I just want to implement, it's not a real life scenario. Take it as a example. I am just trying to implement multiple inheritance with super() function. If you have answer then post it @Blurp

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do here is possible with `super`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does multiple inheritance work with the super() and different \_\_init\_\_() arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855087/how-does-multiple-inheritance-work-with-the-super-and-different-init-arg)

Answer (score 4):

You can directly call `__init__` method of respective parent class.

```
class student(college, library):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("Name:", name)
        college.__init__(self,5560)
        library.__init__(self,60)
```

Comment: Dear, i want to use super() function for this. @Mitiku

Answer (score 2):

**Short:**

You can't and you don't need to use `super()` to call `__init__` with different form. Of course there is a way to do, but I do not recommend that.

**Long:**

Python uses the list of classes to inherit from. You can see that list with
`ClassName.__mro__`. `mro` stands for `Method Resolution Order`

Think about you have three classes, `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC` and `ClassC` extends `ClassA`, and `ClassB` (If you are using python2, `ClassA` and `ClassB` musts extend from `object`)

```
class ClassC(ClassA, ClassB):
```

Then, `ClassC.__mro__` will be like below:

```
(<class '__main__.ClassC'>, <class '__main__.ClassA'>, <class '__main__.ClassB'>, <class 'object'>)
```

So python inherits `ClassC`, `ClassA`, `ClassB` order. And it assumes that methods have same form in this list. This is why you can't use different forms of `__init__` call using `super()`.

If you need to use `super()` and there is no option, you can consider passing argument as `**kwargs`.

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Class A Initialized:", kwargs['a'])

class ClassB():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # super(ClassA, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # if you call above, you'll get type error, because above will call object.__init__ which takes only 1 argument
        print("Class B Initialized:", kwargs['b'])

class ClassC(ClassA, ClassB):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ClassC, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Class C Initialized:", kwargs['c'])

ClassC(a="A", b="B", c="C")
```

And you can get below output :

```
Class B Initialized: B
Class A Initialized: A
Class C Initialized: C
```

But still, I recommend that do not use this form of inheritance, because it is very complicated